# Firebase observeSingleEvent withCancel 100% loss network mode not working in cancelBlock

Tags: xcode, сеть, firebase, swift3, firebase-database

Прислали Reject с стора:

> Performance - 2.1
>
> Also, we were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.
>
> **Next Steps**
>
> 1. Please revise your app and test it on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to ensure it will launch without crashing. Since your iTunes Connect status is Rejected, a new binary will be required.
> 2. Make the desired metadata changes when you upload the new binary.
>
> **Resources**
>
> For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see Tech Note TN2151 *Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports*. For additional information about supporting IPv6 Networks, please refer to *Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks and Supporting IPv6-only Networks*. For a networking overview, please see *About Networking*.

Проблема в том, что при наличии нерабочего интернета (network 100% loss) прога не может получить данные с firebase, и идет бесконечная загрузка, не попадая в CancelBlock. Костыль не могу тоже придумать, так как перепробовал всякие проверки на интернет (они не помогают).

Вот лог:

> ```
> app_instance_id=C2F4F7BE218E4810A18090E113C9B7FF&platform=ios&gmp_version=3600,
> _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2103, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:714764542827..,
> NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.,
> _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}
> ```

Вот функция, в которой проблема:

```
typealias CompletionHandler = (_ success:Bool) -> Void

func loadCDDAta(completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler) {

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        if snapshot.exists() && snapshot.value != nil {
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            self.deleteRecords()
            if let f = value?["Place"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                CoreDataManager.instance.saveCDDict(f)
            }
            else if let f = value?["Place"] as? [AnyObject] {
                CoreDataManager.instance.saveCDArray(f)
            }
            completionHandler(true)
                print("completionHandler(true)")

        } else {
            completionHandler(false)
                print("completionHandler(false)")

    }

}, withCancel: { (error: Error) in

    completionHandler(false)
        print("completionHandler(false)")

})
}
```

[image: Экранный снимок кода]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решыл с помощью проверки доступности интернета

import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class NetworkCheckingClass {

```
    class func isConnectedToNetwork(resultHandler: @escaping (_ isTrue: Bool) -> Void) {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        let urlA = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/")
        let urlB = NSURL(string: "http://baidu.com/")

        let urlDict:[String:NSURL] = ["A":urlA!, "B":urlB!]

        var preference = "A"

        if let temp = defaults.string(forKey: "preferredNetworkURL") {
            preference = temp //check the last successful URL or A by default
        } else {
            defaults.set(preference, forKey: "preferredNetworkURL")
        }

        NetworkCheckingClass.fetchURL(url: urlDict[preference]!, pref:preference) {
            isTrue in
            if isTrue == true {
                print("NETWORK STATUS: \(isTrue)")
                resultHandler(isTrue)
            } else {
                //check the URL which hasn't been checked
                if preference == "A" {
                    preference = "B"
                } else {
                    preference = "A"
                }
                NetworkCheckingClass.fetchURL(url: urlDict[preference]!, pref:preference) {
                    isTrue in
                    print("NETWORK STATUS: \(isTrue)")
                    resultHandler(isTrue)
                }
                //if preference "B" returns true, then Baidu.com is available and user is likely in a country where Google is blocked
            }
        }
    }

    class func fetchURL(url:NSURL, pref:String, resultHandler: @escaping (_ isTrue: Bool) -> Void) {
        print("URL PREFERENCE: \(pref)")
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
        request.timeoutInterval = 10.0

        var returnBool = false
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            ( data, response, error) in
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                    defaults.set(pref, forKey: "preferredNetworkURL") //remember the URL that succeeded and check it first next time
                    returnBool = true
                    resultHandler(returnBool)
                } else {
                    returnBool = false
                    resultHandler(returnBool)
                }
            } else {
                returnBool = false
                resultHandler(returnBool)
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

}